# addAttributeToFilter not working in magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, product-collection

I need to show product collection, if the attribute filter is set to yes .But it's not working. Here is my code

```
<?php /*echo "sadsadsa";*/

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$productCollection = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');

$collection = $productCollection->create()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addFieldToFilter('top_selller','1')
        ->setPageSize(3)?>
<div class="bestsell">       
 <?php foreach ($collection as $product) {
$product_id = $product->getId(); 
/*echo $product_id;*/?>
<div class="bestsll-image">
<?php   $imageHelper  = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper \Image');  
$_product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);
$image_url = $imageHelper->init($product, 'product_page_image_small')->setImageFile($product->getFile())->resize(200)->getUrl();?>
<img src="<?php echo $image_url; ?>" />
</div>
<?php echo $product->getName();
}?> 
</div>
```

Comment: where you have used attAttributeToFilter()?

Comment: actually i have changed that  to addFieldToFilter('top_selller','1')

Comment: is Top_seller attribute?

Comment: yes..Its a custom product attribute

Comment: Make sure there is no typo mistake as you are using "top_selller" (triple L) instead of "top_seller" (Double L)

Answer (score 0):

You should use

> addAttributeToFilter('{Attribute_Code}',1); // use 1 for yes value

Use **1**  for filter collection by ***Yes*** value and **0** for `no value`

***Note that 1/0 boolean value not string***